# Please help me on following error with Django and PostgreSQL with docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /django
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services: 
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes: 
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment: 
     - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    container_name: postgres_db

  web:
    build: .
    volumes: 
      - .:/django
    ports: 
     - "8000:8000"
    links: 
      - db:db
    depends_on: 
     - db
    image: web:django
    container_name: django_container
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And I am getting error like

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Could you provide the `command` you are using to start the compose?

Comment: Share your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this as serious case.

It is resolved. just the issue is to run docker in windows/bash terminal instead of running it in vscode terminals

Comment: I have the same problem too

Comment: I am running the code in the PowerShell terminal, but it is to no avail.